# Finding roots of $\tan(xL) = -\frac{\beta(t)}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials, roots

I've got a tricky problem here, where I've got this problem where I wanna find the positive roots of the following:

$$\tan(xL) = -\frac{\beta(t)}{x}$$

Here, $\beta$ is a function of $t$. I've tried taking the power series of $\tan(xL)$ since there are methods to deal with a polynomial, but are there any other routes for finding the roots? $t$ and $x$ are independent here and I am trying to solve for $x$, where $L$ is a positive constant.

Comment: What is the relation between $t$ and $x$ ? If they are independent, do yo want to solve for $x$ or for $t$ ?

Comment: Also, is $L$ a constant?

Comment: $t$ and $x$ are independent here and I am trying to solve for $x$, where $L$ is a positive constant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are solving for but this may help

\begin{align*}
\tan{(xL)} = -\beta(t)/x\\
\implies
 x\tan{(xL)} +\beta(t)=0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 x\tan{(xL)} 
\longrightarrow
x = \frac{(π n)}{L}\quad L\ne 0, \space n \in\mathbb{ Z} 
\end{align*}

The only integer root appears to be $\space x=0\space$  in which case  $\quad\beta(t)=0$

Answer (score 0):

If you let $y=xL$ and $k=-L \beta(t)$, for a given value of $t$, you need to solve for $y$ the equation
$$y \tan(y)=k$$ There is no explicit solution and you will need some numerical method such as Newton and, as usual, you need a decent starting guess for each of the roots.

However, because of the vertical asmptotes, it will be better o look for the zero of function
$$f(y)=y \sin(y)-k \cos(y)$$ and the $n^{th}$ solution is such that
$$(2n-1)\frac \pi 2 < y_n <(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$$ except the first one if $k>0$.

In the absence of information about how large or small can be $k$, expand $f(y)$ as a series built around $n\pi$ and use series reversion and get, as an *estimate*,
$$y=n\pi  +t-\frac{(k+2) }{2 n\pi  }t^2+\frac{3 (k+2)^2+n^2\pi ^2}{6 n^2\pi ^2 }t^3+O\left(t^4\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac k{n\pi}$$

Trying for the fifth root for $k=10$ (not counting the first one), this gives
$$y=5 \pi+\frac{2}{\pi }-\frac{52}{15 \pi ^3}+\frac{576}{25 \pi ^5} =16.3081$$ With this estimate, Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_n \\
 0 & 16.308067 \\
 1 & 16.259423 \\
 2 & 16.259361
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: When you say expand $f(y)$ as a series built around $n \pi$, do you mean express the functions as a Taylor series?

Comment: @znc204. Yes, for sure. In fact, we could still improve  separating the cases $k>0$ and $k<0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely got me somewhere.